# ReactPlayer height scales to fit more than the page

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-player

On my page, I have a video which I want to encompass the entirety of the webpage's screen. However as of right now, the user must scroll a little bit to reach the bottom, which is not what I want.

My JS:

```
        <div id="page">
            <div id="video-container">
                <ReactPlayer 
                        id="video-player"
                        playing
                        url={flower} 
                        width='100%'
                        height='100%'
                        muted={true}
                        loop
                />
            </div>
        </div>
```

My CSS:

```
#video-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

#video-player {

}
```

I toyed around with adding CSS properties to video-player, but nothing did the trick, so that's why it's empty as of right now. Not sure what I need to tweak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give 100vh height to video player and hide it's overflow.

```
#video-container {
 position: relative;
 display: flex;
 width: auto;
 height: 100vh;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Try `width: 100vw`;